# HTTP Basic Auth only for specific path

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, wshttpbinding

I want to restrict access using HTTP Basic Auth for a specific path so that someone visits `/foo/bar` will be prompted with the authentication form but not `/(.*)`.

I use `mod_rewrite` so I can't put a `.htaccess` inside a folder as usually would do.

Comment: Why can't you put an htaccess file in `/foo/bar`? Are there rules in a parent htaccess file that you can't simply duplicate in `/foo/bar`?

Comment: Because `/foo/bar/` does not exist and I'd rather use a RegEx if possible. So that all "folders" `/foo/b(.+)` require authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password protect a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url)